# Query accounts having only closed lost opportunities

Tags: soql, query

We are planning to reengage closed accounts after a certain amount of time. So, I'm trying to run a report to query accounts that have only closed lost opportunities.

But I'm unable to query accounts that have only closed lost opportunities. Actually, it's returning if accounts have closed lost ones.

Please help me to build the query

```
SELECT ID,Opportunity_Count__c, 
      (SELECT StageName
       FROM Opportunities
       WHERE StageName='Closed Lost') from account Order by Opportunity_Count__c desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want accounts that have *only* closed lost opportunities (e.g. they do not have any closed won opportunities, and they have at least one closed lost opportunity), you want to specify this in your where filter using an `IN AND NOT IN` filter:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE IsWon=FALSE and IsClosed=TRUE) AND
      Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE IsWon=TRUE)
```

Comment: As usually, it works like a charm. Much appreciated!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need a `WHERE` clause if you want to do query filtering.

```
SELECT... FROM Account WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity
    WHERE StageName = 'Closed Lost'
)
```